# SSIS: Parallel script stopping when otherone is complete?

Tags: foreach, ssis, logic

I have 2 parallel foreach loops and both of those have a script task for file writing. Now when loop A finishes its script it stops also loop B which was not done.

What shout I do so, that each loop would be allowed to run untill finished?

Comment: Please post screen shots of the loop properties, and the code of the scripts.   There is not enough information in your question to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

I had used the same resultset object for both scripts. This causes the object to lock up, when one of those succeeds/finishes. So always create a new **object per sql task resultset** or this will occur.